# Bootstrap Navigation bar colour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the colour of the navigation bar of bootstrap.It is black colour.I want to change to another colour.What css bootstrap code should i change ?

HTML Code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried to change the colour of navbar-inverse..but it didn't work

Comment: you are changing it directly on bootstrap.css?

Comment: yes i changed it directly

Comment: yes it didn't work..it is still black colour

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the style of .navbar-inverse that now is `background-color: #222;
border-color: #080808;`

Answer (score 0):

I have succesfully change the color.Using `.container-fluid` can make it..Hopefully

CSS Code :

```
.container-fluid{
background-color:#FF6347;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #1E90FF;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #4169E1;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```